# Android Programming Design for Netflix Movie Landing Style

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'm trying to develop something that has a similar concept to how Netflix is currently working on Android... But I need help with ideas for the implementation... Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

[image]

Naturally this screams to me:
ExpandableListView where the Category Names are the Groups and the movies in each category are the children.  Now here is where it gets tricky; Netflix is currently using a paging theme for scrolling horizontally; and there is a little bit of a preview of the next page of movies (starred and outlined in yellow).

What do you think is a good way to code this?

I currently just have an ExpandableListView and each child is a horizontal scrollview with a linear layout; and I just add each "movie" to the linear layout inside the horizontal scrollview.. however I'd like to do something that reuses cells / is more efficient on system memory.

I'd like to use a ViewPager for each of the children and use a FragmentStatePagerAdapter as the adapter.  Now here are my problems:

1) In this case the movies fill the screen proportionally; I will not know the width of the screen so how can I adjust the elements in the page so that it could look as nice as Netflix does
2) How can I setup a preview for the next page? 
3) Should I be worried about the ExpandableListView stealing focus from the ViewPager children?

Am I thinking about this right or should I try something entirely different to Accomplish this?

Thanks for all of your help!

Comment: Use **`uiautomatorviewer`** to get a better sense of what Netflix itself is using.

Comment: @chocospaz Would you like to share your findings?

Answer (score 0):

here are my findings from using uianimatorviewer as per request: @MinceMan

[image]